# Server Side Rending React Router v6/Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have been stuck on this problem for some time now and I'm not getting anywhere, I am attempting to do SSR with express and am having a lot of trouble with the initial render, I am able to render the first page but no other pages. I've figured out that is because my routes are not being injected with the initial render but this is where I am stuck. I am using React Router v6 for the client routes and express router for the server routes.

--Server Routes--

```
//imports

//-Initial Render-//
router.get('*', initial_render);
router.get("^/$", initial_render);

//-Public-//
router.get('/', public_home);
router.get('/About', about);
router.get('/GrowYourBusiness', grow_your_business);
router.get('/Contact', contact);
router.get('/Login', login)
router.get('/NewUser', new_user)
//logout

//-Client-//  
router.get('/api', client_view);
router.get('/api/Account', account_info);
router.get('/api/SubmitNewLoan', submit_new_loan);
router.get('/api/ActiveLoans', active_loan);
router.get('/api/ActiveLoans/ActiveLoanOverview', active_Loverview);
router.get('/api/InactiveLoans', inactive_loan);
router.get('/api/InactiveLoans/InactiveLoanOverview', inactive_Loverview);
```

--Client Routes--

```
export const Router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        element: <Public />,
        errorElement : <Error />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/About', 
                element: <About />
            }, 
            {
                path: '/GrowYourBusiness', 
                element: <GrowYourBusiness />
            }, 
            {
                path: '/Contact', 
                element: <Contact />
            },
            {
                path: '/Login',
                element: <Login />
            },
            {
                path: '/NewUser',
                element: <NewUser />
            } 

        ],
        path: '/api', 
        exact: true,
        element: <Client />,
        errorElement : <Error />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/api/SubmitNewLoan',
                element: <SubmitNewLoan />
            }, 
            {
                path: '/api/ActiveLoans', 
                element: <ActiveLoans />
            },
            {
                path: '/api/Account', 
                element: <Account />
            } 
        ] 
    }
])

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.hydrateRoot(domContainer,(
    <StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router = {Router} /> 
    </StrictMode>
));
```

this is my most recent attempt at getting everything to work correctly but I can't seem to figure it out. when I use my client routes I get an error saying the document is not defined and when I use my server routes (which I don't think I'm suppose to do) I get an error saying that reduce is not a function which makes sense since they aren't in an array, I've tried to put my serve routes in an array and them use it in my initial render but that doesn't work either.

```
export const initial_render = (req, res, next) => {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'),(err, data) => {
            const context = {Error};
            if(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                return res.send(500).end('Internal Server Error');
            }
            if (context.url) {
                redirect(301, context.url);
            } else {
                const matches = router.reduce((matches, route) => {
                const match = matchPath(req.url, route.path, route) 
                if (match) {
                    matches.push({
                        route, match,
                        promose: route.element.fetchData ?
                        route.element.fetchData(match) : Promise.resolve(null)
                    })
                }
                return matches  
                },[])
                if (matches.length === 0 ) {
                    res.status(404)
                }
                const promise = matches.map((match) => match.promise)
                Promise.all(promise).then((...data) => {
                    content = {}
                    return res.send(data.toString().replace(
                        '<div id="root"></div>', 
                        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                                <StaticRouter location={req.url} context ={content}>
                                   <App routes={router} initialData={data}/>
                                </StaticRouter>
                        )}</div>`))
                }), 
                (error) => {
                    handleError(res, error)
                }
            }
        }
    )}
        

export default initial_render
```

I am just hoping for some clarification on how I am suppose to tackle this issue and some hints in the right direction.

Comment: Just wonder why do you use both server route and client route for same components?

Comment: When I first started making this app I used ejs for the templating and then went to express-react-views which lets me use react on server side so I just kept them. I think this is where I confused about. I've read that you need server routes a api calls and use client routes for everything else. but I've also read you can use both or either or.

Comment: You can use both, but not within same components. You should re-design your whole route scheme. If you use client side routing for your whole APP, it's just like a single page app to the server. If you use route side routing, you client can't get all components needed for your routers, so in your case,you only need one of them.

Comment: Okay, I do like server side routing more then client side. would you know of any examples of how to do the initial render with server routes?

Comment: have a look at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html. Or you can consider using Nextjs.